# CI/CD for adf storage account trigger

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

How to handle change in storage account trigger in azure-data-factory for when deployed in different environment ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have ADF pipelines ready for all the environment, example two separate pipelines for Dev and QA environment with identical resource in each. Means, you should have the same resources in both the environment though parameters would be different.

The changes in different environment have been managed by ARM templates. You need to save the pipeline `ARM Template` and `Parameters` files.

Note: You will pass the Development ARM template and parameters files while creating the `Task` in `DevOps pipeline`. And under `Override template parameters` option you will pass the names of QA pipeline name and resources. This is how you will use resources of Development environment by parameters will be override by QA environment.

[image]

Under `Override template parameters` option you make edits as per your QA environment parameters as in below image.

[image]